# Preg_Match returns unkown modifier 'C' error

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm new to regular expressions and am trying to find a string using preg_match, here's my code:

```
$artist = $row['ARTIST'];
$bool = preg_match("/$artist/", $description, $match);
```

My error is:

```
Unknown modifier 'C' in ...
```

If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape possible special characters in your variable:

```
$bool = preg_match('/' . preg_quote($artist, '/') . '/', $description, $match);
```

[preg_quote() in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php):

> preg_quote() takes str and puts a backslash in front of every
>   character that is part of the regular expression syntax. This is
>   useful if you have a run-time string that you need to match in some
>   text and the string may contain special regex characters.

**Hint:** try echoing your `$artist` variable and you should see which character is causing the problem